# ViewPager and removing pages

Tags: android

OK. I'm quite new to Android, and I have a problem with ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I have a chat application in which the chats are shown in the ViewPager. The chats can be closed dynamically and this works perfectly **until** I navigate out of my app, and return back to the chat activity (and onCreate of the activity is called again).

Let's say I have one chat window open. When I leave the activity, return later, and try to close the page, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1, found: 0
```

Here's my FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
private class ChatPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Map<Integer, Fragment> pageReferenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public ChatPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentManager = fm;
    }

    public ChatFragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = ChatFragment.newInstance(Chat.getChat(position).getUniqueID());
        pageReferenceMap.put(position, fragment);
        return (ChatFragment) fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Chat.getChatCount();
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        pageReferenceMap.remove(position);
    }

    public ChatFragment getFragment(int position) {
        return (ChatFragment) pageReferenceMap.get(position);
    }
}
```

The chats are stored statically in the Chat-class, and getChatCount() simply returns the size of the ArrayList. I am not modifying the ArrayList in anywhere but two places, and these two places should be in sync with notifyDataSetChanged()... that is until the activity is recreated.

In my open(Chat) method I check if the Chat has already been "registered", and trigger notifyDataSetChanged only if it has not (to improve performance).

In my close(Chat) method I simply remove the Chat from the Chat-class, call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter, and BOOM, the exception is thrown.

Is there somekind of culprit I should be aware of when the PageViewer and it's adapter is recreated? How do I keep the new adapter in sync with the already opened chats?

I've tried lots of things but nothing seems to work... I'm sure there's a simple solution to this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... I got this one eventually figured out. It was a stupid listener problem on my behalf. I forgot to unregister a listener from a chat when the activity was closed, and my onClosed(Chat) method got called twice.

Answer (score 0):

After ADT 22 the PagerAdapter has gotten very strict about calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` before calling getCount().
So the solution is simply to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter every time the `size` of the data changes.

Comment: even i'm facing the same problem , is that has been fixed in ADT 22.2.1 ??